# obtener información de las cookies de una web

Tags: php, cookies

Estoy intentando listar las cookies de mi web mediante php. Usando simplemente $_COOKIE obtengo un array con los VALORES de las cookies, pero yo quiero el nombre.
Si pongo $_COOKIE['nombre'] obtengo ese valor; ¿Qué puedo hacer para obtener el nombre y sus otros atributos?.
Digo que lo obtenido es el valor porque si voy al inspector del elemento, en almacenamiento, lo que me muestra es el campo valor.

Muchas gracias de antemano por se ayuda

```html
function listado_cookies(){
 echo '-------------------------------------COOKIES <br>';
 
 foreach ($_COOKIE as $k) {

  echo '--'.$k.'<br>';

 }
 echo '<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'.'nombre  '.$_COOKIE['wp-settings-1'];
    // 'wp-settings-1' es el nombre de una cookie

}
```

[image: imagen de la pestaña de almacenamiento del inspector]

[image: resultado que me muestra el código]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `var_dump` puedes obtener los valores, este pequeño trozo de código debería devolverte las keys

```
if(isset($_COOKIE)) {
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    foreach($_COOKIE as  $key => $val)
    {
      echo "cookie clave= ".$key.", and valor= ".$val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funcionó correctamente (como tu ya sabías). También funciona sin  var_dump, sólo con el foreach. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Cierto, puse el var_dump para comprobar las cookies que había guardadas. Si la respuesta te ha servido, por favor, márcala como correcta :)